# Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0 ou uma de suas dependências

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me ajudar com este erro, pois estou tentando habilitar o `Migrations` em um projeto e aparece esse erro na hora de dar o comando **enable-migrations** no console do gerenciador de pacotes do visual studio.

Mensagem de erro que aparece:

> Exceção ao chamar "CreateInstanceFrom" com "8" argumento(s): "Não foi
>   possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'EntityFramework,
>   Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' ou
>   uma de suas dependências. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo
>   especificado."

Comment: Tem que ser o EF5? Não pode ser o 6?

Comment: Por acaso você instalou o Entity Franework no projeto ex: install-package EntityFramework?

Comment: eu instalei o EF6. eu uso o VS 2013

Comment: Pode editar sua pergunta e colocar o conteúdo do arquivo `Web.config`, mais especificamente a parte de `<runtime>`?

Comment: consegui resolver. o packege não estava instalado. obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

Conforme esclarecimento feito por comentário, o pacote não estava instalado corretamente. O comando a seguir geralmente resolve o problema:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

Também é importante verificar se há o redirecionamento correto do *assembly* no arquivo `Web.config`, tag `<runtime>`:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.1.3.0" newVersion="6.1.3.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```